# How can I get started with integrating AWS Amplify to a Nuxt.js project?

Tags: nuxt.js, aws-amplify

Im recently started working with vue and nuxt. I want to add an AWS backend to my project. I've seen that Amplify is useful but haven't been able to find any resources on how to implement it in nuxt. Any advice?

Comment: Can you show much how much have you implemented ? What's the difficulty?

Comment: @gnomeria I was asking because I wasn't sure if I should use it. I was deciding if I should use that or the serverless framework. Since then I've decided to use sls since I think it better fits my needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm trying to implement as well AWS services as a backend for an app I'm working on.

I managed to get a basic setup working with my Nuxt app doing the following steps.

1.- Create a Amplify Plugin File. (plugins/amplify.js)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Amplify, * as AmplifyModules from 'aws-amplify'
import { AmplifyPlugin, components } from 'aws-amplify-vue'
import aws_exports from '@/aws-exports'
Amplify.configure(aws_exports)

Vue.use(AmplifyPlugin, AmplifyModules)

//register components individually for further use
// Do not import in .vue files
Vue.component('sign-in', components.SignIn)
```

2.- Import the plugin into the Nuxt Config.

```
plugins: [
    {
        src: '~plugins/amplify.js',
        ssr: false
    }
]
```

I'll try and elaborate further or maybe create a tutorial. Hope it helps!

Comment: I wrote a tutorial about it for SSR Nuxt.js https://kodius.com/blog/nuxt-ssr-on-amplify. Hehe in first version I missed documenting this 2 steps you showed :)

Answer (score 3):

This is my setup:

1/ `plugins/amplify.client.js` -> this name makes it execute on client side

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Amplify, * as AmplifyModules from 'aws-amplify'
import { AmplifyPlugin } from 'aws-amplify-vue'
import awsmobile from '~/aws-exports'
Amplify.configure(awsmobile)

Vue.use(AmplifyPlugin, AmplifyModules)

// Make Amplify available in store and Vue instances
export default (_, inject) => {
  inject('Amplify', AmplifyModules)
}
```

2/ `nuxt.config.js`

```js
plugins: ['@/plugins/amplify.client.js'],
```

It let me use commands such as `this.$Amplify.Hub` or `store.$Amplify` so I have access to the main functions anywhere.

Comment: `Vue.prototype.$Amplify = AmplifyModules;` works for me if you just want to use Amplify in this.$Amplify