# Force the login page using Amplify with Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, aws-amplify

I have recently integrated AWS Amplify in my Nuxt.js website, I choose to didn’t pass by the amplify-cli. My authentification is working great, but you have to go by yourself on the page `/login.vue`. I would like to force the authentification by simply redirect the user on the login page if he isn’t logged.

I tried different things with the middleware part. Here what I have done:

```js
// middleware/authenticated.js

import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'

export default function ({ redirect }) {
    if (Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() == undefined) {
      return redirect('/login')
    }
}
```

```js
// plugins/Amplify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Amplify, * as AmplifyModules from 'aws-amplify'
import { AmplifyPlugin, components } from 'aws-amplify-vue'

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        identityPoolId: 'eu-west-1:xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx',
        mandatorySignIn: true,
        region: 'eu-xxx-x',
        identityPoolRegion: 'eu-xxxx-x'
    }
})

Vue.use(AmplifyPlugin, AmplifyModules)
```

Comment: so what isnt working? Your code looks generally like it should do what you described

Comment: Actually, my home page load without passing by the login page...

Comment: how do u define middelware ? is it beeing called at all?

Comment: I simply did this on my home page: ```export default {
  middleware: 'authenticated', }```

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue. Apparently Nuxt's middleware happens either on Server Side or Client but not on both (or only client mode of some sort).
[You can read through this thread](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2653)
Would like to know if/how you solved it...

Answer (score 4):

Avoid using the middleware as it renders on server on first load. AWS amplify is not available on server side. The alternative is to use mixins:

mixins/authentication.js

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'

export default {
  async mounted() {
    if (this.$store.state.account.authorized) {
      return
    }

    try {
      let user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({ bypassCache: false })
      if (!user) {
        this.$router.push('/login')
      }
    } catch (err) {
      this.$router.push('/login')
    }
  }
}
```

Then import in each page you wish to be authenticated (or within a certain layout).

```
 import authentication from "@/mixins/authentication.js";

 ...

 export default {
   mixins: [authentication],
   ...
```

This might cause a fracture of second 'blink', until redirect back to login page because the code happens on 'mounted'.

Any more elegant suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will keep this topic as unanswered if someone has a more elegant suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60783792/3474490

Then I do the authentication in `middleware/auth.js`

```js
export default function({ store, route, redirect }) {
  return store.$Amplify.Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    .catch(() => {
      this.$router.push('/')
    })
    .then((user) => {
      // Set user in store
      store.commit('setUser', user)

      // Requires authentication
      if (route.meta.some((meta) => meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (!user) redirect('/login/')
      }

      // Requires to be anonymous
      if (route.meta.some((meta) => meta.requiresAnonymous)) {
        if (user) redirect('/dashboard/')
      }
    })
}
```

Then in pages I just need to set `meta` tags `requiresAuth` or `requiresAnonymous` if applicable.